# Генерирующийся PHP файл

Tags: php

Хотел задать несколько вопросов:

1. Имеется веб-хранилище данных, все папки с файлами лежат по адресу 
   `site.su/download/...` Например пользователь выбрал понравившийся материал под псевдо-номером `216` и решил загрузить, нажав кнопку "Скачать" на главной странице.  Далее пользователь попадает на `site.su/download/216` и файл автоматический загружается. Подскажите как можно реализовать данную затею.
2. Из этого вытекает второй вопрос: Как скрыть расширение у прилегающего файла (`216.php` ==> `216`)?

[Наглядный пример : http://howdyho.net/ ]
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Сайт конечно ужасный -.-

Comment: `RewriteRule ^download/?$ download.php [L]`. И дальше уже работаем с `download.php`

Answer (score 0):

Через `.htaccess` отправляем все ссылки вида `site.su/download/\d+` на какой-то единый обработчик, который берёт номер, преобразует его (например находит по нему путь к файлу в базе данных), читает файл и отдаёт его с нужными заголовками.

Comment: Не подскажете, как именно это реализовать?

Comment: Так уже сказал. Или Вам нужен прям рабочий код? Это на фриланс.